# Como dizer "dormir com alguém" sem conotação sexual?

Tags: expressões

No português (pelo menos brasileiro) é comum ligar a expressão "dormir com alguém" com sexo. Veja:

> Ele dormiu com ela na noite passada.

Como dizer essa expressão de forma que não tenha conotação sexual?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aqui em Portugal, se disseres que *ele dormiu com ela*, as pessoas também vão pensar que houve relação sexual ou que no mínimo existiu uma forte probabilidade de ter havido relação sexual. E se dissesses *ele foi para a cama com ela*, então é que era 100% certo que tinha havido coisa. Uma maneira de evitar essa interpretação é usar *em casa dela* em vez de *com ela*:

> **Ele dormiu em casa dela a noite passada.**
>
> **Ele ficou em casa dela a noite passada.**

Mesmo assim as pessoas poderiam pensar que houve qualquer coisa mais, mas nenhuma das frases acima, por si só, implica relação sexual. Mas as pessoas poderiam pensar que tu não estavas a contar tudo, ou que eles não te tinham contado tudo.

Ouvindo qualquer das frases acima, eu pensaria que eles tinham dormido em camas separadas e até mesmo em quartos diferentes. Isto vai para além da linguagem: é simplesmente porque nos tempos atuais não se espera que um homem e uma mulher ou mesmo dois adolescentes de sexos opostos partilhem uma cama se não estiverem numa relação. Se por acaso eu quisesse dizer que eles partilharam a cama por alguma necessidade e sem haver mais nada, creio que a única solução seria explicitar tudo. Por exemplo:

> **Já não havia mais lugar onde dormirem e tiveram de ficar na mesma cama.**
>
> **No hotel só havia um quarto com cama de casal, e eles tiveram de a partilhar.**

Comment: Eu não ouviria o mesmo que tu, nas duas primeiras frases. A minha mente aborrecida certamente consideraria imediatamente que houve diversão, *e só depois* justificaria com um "ou então não, estamos em <ano atual> e as pessoas podem ser amigas com pessoas do sexo oposto sem perderem a honra". Mas sim, concordo bem com a tua resposta.

Comment: @ANeves, mente aborrecida?! Diz antes depravada!

Comment: Me soa com menos chances de conotação sexual se for "Passou a noite na casa dela". Mas sem mais informações do contexto, é praticamente impossível não pensar que house "diversão".

Comment: @Luciano, concordo que, dependendo do contexto e do que tu sabes das pessoas em questão, é possível pensar que houve "diversão". Se eu disser, "só sei que a festa acabou às duas da manhã e depois o João foi levá-la a  casa", também se vai pensar que possivelmente houve "diversão"; é que nós somos incapazes de não imaginar diversão se houver a mínima possibilidade. Mas se disseres "dormir com ela" queres mesmo dizer que houve; se disseres as outras coisas, não afirmas que houve, mas também não negas; o ouvinte é depois livre de imaginar o que quiser.

Comment: Também me lembrei de *passar*. Acabei por não incluir por me parecer que *ficar* é interpretado como dormir/ficar alojado, enquanto *passar* me parece mais vago. Por exemplo, ele foi já hoje para o Rio, porque tinha de lá estar no dia seguinte às 8 da manhã--aqui eu tendo a dizer "ficou em casa dela"; Mas, ele não chegou a vir a casa esta noite--aqui, eu tendo mais a dizer  "vim a saber que ele **passou** a noite em casa dela/na praia/às voltas por aí" se quiser dar a entender que não sei porquê nem o que aconteceu; mas "o carro dele avariou, e ele ficou em casa dela". Pode ser impressão minha

Comment: Concordo com @Jacinto.  Não estamos aqui a discutir o que se passa na cabeça das pessoas, mas o que a frase diz de concreto.  Até mesmo uma frase inocente como "Já era bem tarde, eu levei a Maria até sua casa no meu carro e João levou a Teresa" pode ser interpretada com malícia dependendo da cabeça "aborrecida" de quem ouve (ou dependendo da fama das pessoas envolvidas).

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que em todo o Brasil, mas sei que no estado do Rio Grande do Sul, usamos a palavra **pousar** no sentido de dormir na casa de alguém. E nesse caso, sem nenhuma conotação sexual.

> 1. Pousar
>      Significado de Pousar Por Anderson Ribeiro (SP) em 17-10-2009
>      Dormir, pernoitar, pasei a noite
>      Eu pousei na casa
>      de meu amigo.

Fonte: [Dicionário Informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/pousar/)

Essa palavra também tem o mesmo significado segundo em [Como Escreve?](http://comoescreve.com.br/pousar-ou-posar/)

> Pousar: o mesmo que descansar, colocar, aterrissar. Significa também,
>   pernoitar, passar a noite.

Comment: Aqui no Paraná usam bastante essa palavra. Bem lembrado!

Comment: Esse sentido de *pousar* vem também nos dicionários tradicionais: [Aulete 7,8](http://www.aulete.com.br/pousar) ou [Michaelis 6](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/pousar/). Em Portugal, na minha zona, não se costuma ouvir *pousar* com esse sentido, mas vem no dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa, com a nota que é desusado. Mas existem por aqui as *pousadas*, uns pequenos hotéis, estalagens.

Comment: Aqui no Rio Grande do Sul é ainda muito usado, principalmente quando se é criança. É comum ir pousar nas casas dos amigos. :D

Comment: No Rio de Janeiro eu nunca ouvi.  Dizemos muito "ficamos em uma pousada", mas não é comum ouvir-se "pousei".

Comment: No  RS ao falar, usamos *posar*, o *u* não é pronunciado.

Answer (score 1):

*Eles dormiram juntos a noite passada.*

*Eles dormiram na mesma cama a noite passada.*

Mas repara que existe sempre alguma ambiguidade.

Não acho que o problema aqui seja a conotação, mas o facto de em certos contextos se assumir automaticamente que houve algo mais.

Portanto a única forma é ser num contexto onde não haja essa assunção ou esclarecer melhor, ou simplesmente esclarecer que foi só dormir.

Answer (score -5):

Considere a expressão *"passar a noite juntos"*. Por exemplo:

> Visto que ela não se sentiu bem durante o evento, não quis dormir só no hotel. Passaram a noite juntos.

Comment: Eu editei a postagem para torná-la mais adequada a uma resposta do que um simples exemplo. Porém, não adicionei qualquer coisa extra além de uma simples introdução e marcação de texto. Se achar necessário, pode revertê-la.